# Prestashop Custom Webservice

Tags: php, webservice, prestashop

Buenos días, estoy desarrollando un módulo que hará uso de la funcionalidad de webservices de Prestashop 1.6.

En mi caso intento mandar datos de una tienda a otra con un servicio web custom, es decir, he creado un webservice propio, activado los métodos que me interesan, pero a la hora de implementar las funciones CRUD, estoy un poco perdido.

Me gustaría saber como se interpretan las URL's pasándole parámetros para, por ejemplo, consultar un item por ID, borrar un item por ID o crear uno nuevo. Eso si, usando la manera de implementar como se hace aquí: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib/blob/master/examples/Retrieve.php

Edito: Os pongo aquí la explicación y el código. Los datos a recuperar y grabar se recuperan/guardan en una tabla nueva que he dado de alta.

**Esta es la clase que estiende del webservice request core para implementar mi webservice propio**

```
class WebserviceRequest extends WebserviceRequestCore
{
    public function __construct()          
    {
        include_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'directorioModulo'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'models'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'ClaseParaImplementarModuloCustom.php');
    }
}
```

**Esta clase ClaseParaImplementarModuloCustom.php es donde se debe hacer toda la lógica del Webservice. (Entiendo que las funciones CRUD)**

```
class CentralizedStoreAssociated extends ObjectModel
{
    //Campos de la clase
    public $id;
    public $store_name;
    public $store_url;
    public $store_api_key;
    public $store_contact_email;

    //Definición de la clase/objeto
    public static $definition = [
        'table'     => 'centralized_stores',
        'primary'   => 'id_centralizedstore',
        'multilang' => false,
        'multilang_shop' => false,
        'fields' => array(
            'store_id' => ['type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate' => 'isInt', 'size' => 256],
        ),
    ];
}

//Definición de los parámetros del servicio web. Aquí es donde entiendo que deben definirse las funciones para el CRUD en associations.
protected $webserviceParameters = [
        'objectNodeName' => 'store',
        'objectsNodeName' =>'centralized_stores',
        'associations' => [
            'storeDetails' => array('getter' => 'getStoreDetails',     'resource' => 'storeDetails',
            'fields' => array(
                'store_name'            => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isString', 'size' => 256],
                'store_url'             => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isUrl', 'size' => 2038],
                'store_api_key'         => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isString', 'size' => 32],
                'store_contact_email'   => ['type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isEmail', 'size' => 254],
            ),
        ),
    ]
];
```

Finalmente he definido una función para el getter => getStoreDetails que no es más que una función para obtener los datos de una tienda desde la tabla custom, por medio de la URL http://mitiendaprestashop/api/centralized_store/1

Espero haberlo dejado todo más claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas, tendrás que hacer uso de **$_POST** y **$_GET**, los dos transportan datos, pero la diferencia es:

GET: lleva los datos de forma "visible" al cliente (navegador web). El medio de envío es la URL. Los datos los puede ver cualquiera. Ej: http://unaweb.com/**questions**/**28654**/**prestashop-custom-webservice**.

POST: consiste en datos "ocultos" (porque el cliente no los ve) enviados por un formulario cuyo método de envío es post. Es adecuado para formularios. Los datos no son visibles.

La ventaja de usar POST es que estos datos no son visibles al usuario de la web. En el caso de usar get, el propio usuario podría modificar la URL escribiendo diferentes parámetros a los reales en su navegador, dando lugar a que la información tratada no sea la prevista.

A partir de aquí has de realizar tu CRUD, te recomiendo que uses el método POST, te dejo un ejemplo sencillo de código:

```
<body>
<form name="formularioDatos" method="post" action="ejemploRequest2.php">
<p> CÁLCULO DEL PRECIO MEDIO DE UN PRODUCTO </p>
<br/>
Introduzca el precio del producto en el establecimiento número 1, en euros: <input type="text" name="precio1" value="">
<br/> <br/>
Introduzca el precio del producto en el establecimiento número 1, en euros: <input type="text" name="precio2" value="">
<br/> <br/>
Introduzca el precio del producto en el establecimiento número 3, en euros: <input type="text" name="precio3" value="">
<br/> <br/>
<input value="Calcular" type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

[image: archivo html]

[image: archivo servidor]

Comment: Muchas gracias @sakulino, pero creo que tengo que concretar más para profundizar más. Se que los tiros van por ahi, pero con los webservices de prestashop se ha de trabajar de manera diferente. Edito pregunta con más información.

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta, puedes ver los detalles más arriba.

Comment: ¡¿En serio esta es la respuesta correcta a la pregunta?!